# How to make multiple plots in r?

Tags: r, graph, scatter-plot

I have a large matrix `mdat` (1000 rows and 16 columns) contains first column as `x` variable and other columns as `y` variables. What I want to do is to make scatter plot in R having 15 figures on the same window. For example:

```
mdat <- matrix(c(1:50), nrow = 10, ncol=5)
```

In the above matrix, I have 10 rows and 5 columns. Is it possible that to use  the first column as variable on x axes and other columns as variable on y axes, so that I have four different scatterplots on the same window? Keep in mind that I will ***not*** prefer `par(mfrow=`, because in that case I have to run each graph and then produce them on same window. What I need is a package so that I will give it just data and `x`, `y` varaibeles, and have graphs on same windows.
Is there some package available that can do this? I cannot find one.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "15 figures on the same window"? One plot with 15 lines showing 15 relationships (probably in different colors)?  Or 15 separate plots in a panel, perhaps 4 row x 4 cols with one plot missing?  In the 2nd case, shuja's answer will work.

Comment: shujas answer work. Now i have other question about your first case. Is it possible to have 15 line with different colours on same window, with the explanation of each colour so that one can easiliy distinguish that which colour represents to which variable?

Comment: @user4299 Most people will tell you that 15 colors is too many to distinguish, but see my edits for a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user4299 You can re-write shujaa's `ggplot` command in this form, using `qplot` which means 'quick plot' which is easier when starting out.  Then instead of faceting, use `variable` to drive the color.  So first command produces the same output as shujaa's answer, then the second command gives you all the lines on one plot with different colors and a legend.

```
qplot(data = molten, x = V1, y = value, facets = . ~ variable, geom = "point")
qplot(data = molten, x = V1, y = value, color = variable, geom = "point")
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the simplest base R way is `mfrow` (or `mfcol`)

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2)) ## the window will have 2 rows and 2 columns of plots
for (i in 2:ncol(mdat)) plot(mdat[, 1], mdat[, i])
```

See `?par` for everything you might want to know about further adjustments.

Another good option in base R is `layout` (the help has some nice examples). To be fancy and pretty, you could use the `ggplot2` package, but you'll need to reshape your data into a long format.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
molten <- melt(as.data.frame(mdat), id = "V1")

ggplot(molten, aes(x = V1, y = value)) +
    facet_wrap(~ variable, nrow = 2) +
    geom_point()
```

Alternatively with colors instead of facets:

```
ggplot(molten, aes(x = V1, y = value, color = variable)) +
    geom_point()
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
library(lattice)
x = mdat[,1]; y = mdat[,-1]
df = data.frame(X = x, Y = as.vector(y),
                Grp = factor(rep(seq_len(ncol(y)), each=length(x))))
xyplot(Y ~ X | Grp, df)
```